# Kotlin. How to insert new records if data doesn't exist in Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm a beginner in asynchronous operations. My goal is to check whether data with specific date already exist in Room database or not, if not then start download from server and insert it to Room. But my following codes execute `TODO: Processing Data` in Fragment twice coz the coroutine re-execute it when the `TODO: download insert new data` finished

Here my codes:

**birdDAO.kt**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM birds_table WHERE birdDate =:rDate ORDER BY birdId")
        fun getBirdBySingleDate(rDate: Int): LiveData<List<Bird>>
```

**birdRepository.kt**

```
fun getBirdBySingleDate(rDate: Int) = birdDao.getBirdBySingleDate(rDate)
```

**birdViewModel.kt**

```
fun getBirdByDate(rDate: Int) = birdRepository.getBirdBySingleDate(rDate)
```

**Fragment.kt**

```
private fun loadBirdData(jDate: Int) {
      val listBirdByDate = birdViewModel
            .getBirdByDate(jDate)
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ birds ->
            
                val size = birds.size
                
                if(size > 0) {
                    //TODO Processing Data
                }
                else
                {
                    //TODO: download n insert new data
                
                }
            }
}
```

The question is how to write the codes that only execute one-shot Room query? I tried to remove `LiveData` type in **birdDAO.kt** and  change **Fragment.kt** like this:

```
private fun loadBirdData(jDate: Int) {
    val listBirdByDate = birdViewModel.getBirdByDate(jDate)

    if(listBirdByDate.isNotEmpty) {
          //TODO Processing Data
    }
    else
    {
          //TODO: download n insert new data
                
    }
}
```

but the `listBirdByDate.isNotEmpty` line gave me this error:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline fun <T> Array<out TypeVariable(T)>.isNotEmpty(): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
```

Or what is the best way to get my goal done? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning list of birds , you can create another query to get the count of found entries for particular date and in the view Model , I guess, you want to start downloading data from server once your verify that the count is zero.

You can change your viewModel from

> fun getBirdByDate(rDate: Int) =
> birdRepository.getBirdBySingleDate(rDate)
> to

```
fun getBirdByDate(rDate :Int){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        var count= 2  //we don't want two in db though
        
        //withContext and also with main dispatcher we assure that the count 
        //vairable gets updated , I recently came to know that we can actually  
       // use main as well immediate  on Dispatcher inside viewmodel , so 
        //including it :P 
        //Thanks to #commonware
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate){
            count = //your repository function to get dao using Dispatche.IO
        }
        if(count == 0){
            //start downloading from server and update data in db
        }else if(count==1){
            //get the list from db
        }else
        {
            //show error
        }
    }
}
```

you can actually do better logic for if and else (use when for kotlin), I am trying to give you some idea as I am also new to android.

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Query("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM birds_table)")
  fun hasBirds(): Boolean
```

In your Dao add above code. Then use following code in your logic

```
          if(mDao.hasBirds()) {
                //TODO Processing Data
            } else {
                //TODO: download n insert new data
            }
```